# jsFiddle could be indexed or I keep my codes private?

Tags: privacy, jsfiddle

I'm worried about using some data in a fiddle (jsFiddle) because these data shouldn't be public.

Can Google index jsFiddle? I saved the fiddle but I don't save a title for it so it shouldn't became public..

However, the fiddle URL is still visible even if I log out from jsFiddle...

Some clarifications?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you putting something into jsfiddle if you don't want it to be public?

Comment: Nothing worrying, but I was thinking about to not share some URL, used into fiddles, for example...anyway..my fiddle URL (jsfiddle.net/mynick/fiddleID) is no longer visible (Error 404)..maybe because I deleted from my dashboard ?

Comment: Why are you putting something on the World Wide Web that you don't want to be public?  Taking it away is no guarantee that it won't remain away.  If it's important that your data not be available, don't make it available.

Comment: Because jsFiddle is a nice, quick tool that makes it easy to quickly test things out (e.g. loading in frameworks by just clicking a checkbutton)? Some of these quick tests may not be useful (at least not just yet) for a public audience. Or, it could also be that the code isn't working properly. Or perhaps you only wish to share the code to a selected group of people. Or, some people may be using jsFiddle as an online stash for various experiements that you do for your own learning (at a stage where you don't feel anyone else would learn much from your awkwardly messy first attempts).

Answer (score 26):

There are currently two modes of privacy, one is public (where you add a title and description), this fiddle will show up in your dashboard and your public fiddle-list. The other mode is semi-public, where you don'y add description or title, hence the fiddle is **only** visible for you in your dashboard - crawlers shouldn't be able to reach there, hence shouldn't index your fiddles.

That said, the Beta version of JsFiddle has more privacy modes, including the much anticipated "private fiddle" - this functionality will be probably available only for subscribers.

Best,
Oskar (JsFiddle co-creator)