# How do I make it so people can't save my JSFiddle over my own?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I'm having an issue with JSFiddle where when I go to my Dashboard and open up a JSFiddle owned by me that I was working on, it became rev 52 (mine was rev 43) and was COMPLETELY edited. As in all my code was gone and it was replaced with some random code that has nothing to do with my original Fiddle.

Am I doing something wrong with the way I setup my JSFiddle? Or is there something I can do?

Comment: It annoys me as well (but I'm afraid the question will be closed as offtopic)

Comment: Make an account and then reference this question on [webapps.stackexchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11024/how-do-i-change-a-jsfiddle-to-no-longer-be-public)

Comment: [This question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/11027) seems relevant (though it's not a perfect solution).

Comment: Here's [an answer from the creator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6409535/778118) of jsFiddle.

Comment: The url of your fiddle gets appended with a version number when it is updated.  Change the number in the url to /43/.  Then hit update.  It will create /53/ and you will have your code as the latest revision.

Answer (score 5):

If you're logged into jsFiddle, then only the logged in user owns the base version.  I only share the base version.  Others can make their own versions, but the base version never changes unless I set a new version to the base.  "Use the base, Luke".

If I need to share multiple versions, I just hit Fork and make a new base version to share.  This way my version that I created and shared is ALWAYS the base version.  I also never have to remember which version is my version as it's always just the base version.